# Advanced custom fields - pulling data in from another page

Tags: wordpress

Hello I am using advanced custom fields and I am trying to pull data from multiple pages and display it on another

I set up a relationship field called "data", and then on page X where the relationship field is displayed I have chosen page Y where I want to pull the data from

```
<?php if( get_field('data') ): ?>
     <?php the_field('special_offer'); ?> <!--// get content from page Y -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

I can't get this to work though and Im presuming the above is wrong, does anyone know how I could do this please?

Hopefully I have explained it clearly

Cheers

*This seems to be the solution, although having troubles pulling the_content etc

```
  <?php  $offers = get_field('data'); ?>

    <?php if( $offers ): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach( $offers as $location ): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $location->ID ); ?>">
                    <?php echo get_the_title( $location->ID ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to include the page ID in the code:

```
<?php if( get_field('data', 123) ): ?>
<?php the_field('special_offer', 123); ?> <!--// get content from page Y -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

From the documentation:
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-get-values-from-another-page/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there not a way of doing this without setting static id's? I.e. the pages that the data will be pulled from needs to be chosen using the relationship field, so this can all be managed inside wordpress